# Unsure about the component type or model. Drill charger. Parkside 14.4 V

Tags: batteries, identification, components, charger

What is the component in the circle? This is for a charger to charge a battery for a drill. Is it a transformer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a choke which with the yellow capacitor form a mains input filter.

Comment: What makes you think you need to change it?

Comment: Because I see a burnt black stain on one of the pins. I did a current continuation test. It beeps on one side but not the other. The other side doesn't beep.

Comment: if the input filter is burnt, that points to a fault in your device, and quite likely, something else is more severely broken. Let's be honest here: the charger was 13€ at [lidl](https://www.lidl.de/p/parkside-ladegerat-plg-20-a1-65-watt-mit-led-ladeindikator-ladeabschaltung/p100302890), so you can probably buy one for 10€ off ebay. No way on earth you could replace things for that cost, seeing that you need to source components including shipping, test and solder them. And you'd still get a fire hazard. So e-waste-recycle this, buy a used one.

Comment: ebay: https://www.ebay.de/itm/275078483115?hash=item400bf48cab:g:sjcAAOSwTFVhx2Hx currently 1€.

Comment: Places from where to not buy components: Lidl, Ebay, Aliexpress, shady dudes in dark alleys.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common mode choke for filtering mains input.

Comment: Thanks. Does it matter what values I use? On the side is market TY 52

Comment: You can simply remove it and replace it with two pieces of wire. What happened to R7? It may have been a fusible resistor. Nevertheless, for the choke to fail there must’ve been some provocation. Chokes don’t tend to fail by themselves. I’d expect other problems.

Comment: @Kartman I wouldn't be so sure about the optionality of the component. Best case, you're just breaking the law with respect to electromagnetic emissions. Worst case, this is part of some power factor correction system and things will fail.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, in this instance it wouldn’t be me breaking the law and the laws that apply to your jurisdiction might not apply to mine.